# Style does not work on Button

Tags: android

Here is my XML for a Button:

```
<Button
  style="@style/Btest"
  android:id="@+id/Button01"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Some text"
  />
```

And here is the style XML for the Button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Btest" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16dip</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But, the style XML has no effect on the Button. If I skip the style XML and apply the style directly in the Button XML, things work as intended.

What am I missing?

Comment: The XML looks fine. Have you tried a clean build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the `parent="@android:style/Widget.Button"` for a particular reason?  You only need to specify a `parent` when you want to inherit from another style.  What happens if you remove this?

Comment: Hi! Actually, it works but I cannot see it in the editor/Eclipse. I thought that Id be able to do so, but apparently not. Thats annoying, since then you dont really know how it looks until you deploy it. Makes it hard to get right - time consuming =(

Comment: @Ted You can change the Eclipse editor theme in the upper part of the Graphical Layout view.

Comment: @Dave I just want to change the background color of `Button` using style, but it changes `Button`'s everything including background color, like the `parent="android:Widget.Button"` is completely overridden. Can you help with this?